# How to define a probability function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I just started learning some probability theory and came across the definition of a probability space. The definitions are not defined using measure theoretic terms. They define a probability space as a set S together with a probability function P on the subsets of S satisfying
0$\leq$ P $\leq$ 1. Then they give the following example: Suppose we have two dice.

What is the probability that one 6 is rolled. Now I get how they got to the answer by looking at all the possible outcomes. But nowhere did they define the probability function that is being used. Then I was looking at an example in a measure theory book in which they give the following example: Suppose we have the set A = {40, 41, . . . ,49} and define the probability function by P = (Counting measure on A)/10. Then we find the probability of the set B $\subset$ A where B = {$w\in A$ : w is even}. This makes sense.

My question is, I suppose there is some implicit function defined in the example of the dice, but why not define it first and then use that to find the probability.

The same goes with other examples, they don't tend to define the probability function and rather just use intution to get the asnwer.

Comment: You may have answered your own question or somewhere in the notes/book the term equiprobable events was used, meaning all experiment outcomes are equally likely

Comment: If they don't define the probability function explicitly, it'd be nice if they would at least state some assumptions that they are making about the probability function. For example, let $E_i$ be the event that the first die shows $i$ dots, and let $F_j$ be the event that the second die shows $j$ dots. Then we might assume that $P(E_i) = 1/6$ and $P(F_j) = 1/6$ and $P(E_i \cap F_j) = P(E_i) P(F_j)$ for all $i,j$ with $1 \leq i, j \leq 6$. However, such assumptions are often not stated explicitly. (Perhaps the author thinks that level of explicitness might bog things down.)

Comment: @Paul Yeah I thought the same. I suppose you could define a function following your intuition. I just though it would be nice if they would define the function. Also, they never use the term equiprobable events. The approach from a measure theory perspective seems so much better but the class I am in is not taking that approach.

Comment: @littleO Yeah that would be nice if they provided some directions towards the answer. But honestly, the book is just full of terrible exposition of topics.

Comment: Plenty of bad books out there. The book 'Introduction to probability theory and statistical inference' by Harold Larson is a nice half way point between practical probability and the dryer measure theory.